# Execute script in Cordova Webview

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using [this](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/inAppBrowser/) InAppbrowser plugin
After following the suggestions in answers I still cannot get this working.

My app.js

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  var app = angular
      .module('starter', ['ionic', 'ngCordova'])
      .run(function($ionicPlatform){
        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
          if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
            cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
          }
          if(window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
          }
        });
      });

      app.controller("starter", function($scope, $rootScope, $cordovaInAppBrowser){

          console.log("inside controller");

          $cordovaInAppBrowser.open('https://google.com','_self', {location: "no"})
              .then(function(event) {
                console.log("success");
              })
              .catch(function(event) {
                console.log(event)
              });

          $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstop', function(e, event){
              console.log("loadstop called");
              $cordovaInAppBrowser.executeScript({                      
                  code: 'alert("from app to browser");'
              });
          });

          $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loaderror', function(e, event){
            console.log(e);
          });

        })

        angular.element(document).ready(function() {
          document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
            console.log("deviceready called");
            angular.bootstrap(document, ["starter"]);
          }, false);
        });


}());
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
    <title></title>
    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ngCordova/dist/ng-cordova.js"></script>

    <script src="cordova.js"></script>     
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="src/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <ion-pane ng-controller="starter">
   </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

config.xml

```
 <content src="index.html"/>
  <allow-navigation href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-navigation href="https://*/*"/>
  <access browserOnly="true" origin="*" />
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false"/>
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"/>
  <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
  <feature name="StatusBar">
    <param name="ios-package" onload="true" value="CDVStatusBar"/>
  </feature>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
    <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
  </platform>
  <icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png"/>
```

console output

```
I/chromium(18704): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(130)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
I/chromium(18704): [INFO:CONSOLE(46)] "deviceready called", source: file:///android_asset/www/src/app.js (46)
I/chromium(18704): [INFO:CONSOLE(20)] "inside controller", source: file:///android_asset/www/src/app.js (20)
```

`$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstop` event never fires. 
 **Cordova version 6.0.0, ionic version 1.7.14**

Comment: Can you setup up a listener for loaderror and see what you get?  $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loaderror', function(e, event){
alert('SomethingMeaningful');
  });

Comment: @SteveKennedy loaderror does not fire at all

Comment: hmm. Interesting.  Do you have this code inside the deviceready() method?

Comment: Yes the code is inside deviceReady

Comment: What are your CSP and whitelisting rules?

Comment: @mundella please share your app.js also

Comment: added both CSP & app.js

Comment: @mundella you need to initialize `ngCordova` in angular.module also

Comment: I sure have. Otherwise URL wouldn't be opening.

Comment: @mundella no you are not adding it , url opening is ddifferent

Comment: @Webruster Please look at my latest code

Comment: Any reason for using the IIFE here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

event listeners shouldn't work if you use `_self`.

When you use `_self` you are loading the website inside the cordova webview, not the inAppBrowser webview, and then you are replacing all your existing code with the code from the website you load, so when your page finish loading, your code is gone and won't be executed.

You have to use `_blank` to open the real inAppBrowser window.

Comment: So there is no way to inject JS in webview? When we use `_self`

Comment: Not from javascript. If you modify cordova java classes, the SystemWebviewClient class should have the methods to handle the webview start and stop events, you can make them execute some javascript

Comment: Yes. The other issue is `<input type="file">` does not work when `_blank` target is used. So its pretty much either or. I cannot achieve both - injecting javascript and working `<input type="file">`. Webview handles file browser opening successfully.

Comment: yeah, input file not working on inAppBrowser is a known issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9148. You can try to use another inAppBrowser plugin based on crosswalk (see available plugins here http://cordova.apache.org/plugins/?q=crosswalk). But using crosswalk will increase your apk size.

Comment: tried this crosswalk plugin - https://www.npmjs.com/package/dtworkshop-inappcrossbrowser. No luck :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you can use this plugin to inject Cordova into any website that you load into webview: https://github.com/sberan/cordova-plugin-injectview

Also, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9148 is already closed